# System.UnauthorizedAccessException: "cannot write to the registry key"

Tags: c#, winforms, реестр

Во время отладки программы появляется исключение:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: "cannot write to the registry key"

Ниже скриншот с ошибкой и код, на котором она возникает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сам код:

```
private void AddToWhiteList(RegistryUninstallInfo info)
{
    Applications.Remove(info);
    WhiteList.Add(info);
    using (var section = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(regWhiteList))
    {
        section.CreateSubKey(info.RegistryKeyName);
    }
}
```

Если из кода что-то будет непонятно я объясню.

Comment: Прочитайте саму ошибку, а не сообщение, что увидите? `Unauthorized Access`, вбиваем в переводчик (если не знаем английского) и видим `несанкционированный доступ`. А теперь думаем, почему такое? Наверно, у вас нет прав на эту ветку реестра, ибо приложение не запущено от администратора?

Comment: Код частично похож на ваш. Думаю, ответ по ссылке сможет помочь вам решить эту проблему. Если нет, то дайте знать - будем разбираться. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7202870/13123688

Comment: У меня или какие-то непонятки, или я не вижу в упор сходства с этим кодом (stackoverflow.com/a/7202870/13123688)

Comment: Вероятно вы пытаетесь вызвать `CreateSubKey` для ключа, который уже существует. Что в реестре то находится? Посмотрите редактором реестра. Есть там ключ или нет?

Comment: Нет, там нету ключа, я думаю правильнее будет добавить сюда код, где эта ветка создается

Comment: 'private void InitWhiteList()
        {
            var section = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(regWhiteList);
            try
            {
                if (section == null)
                {
                    section = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(regWhiteList);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                section?.Dispose();
            }
        }'

Comment: const string regWhiteList = @"SOFTWARE\WhiteListManager\WhiteList";

Comment: Код надо писать прямо в вопрос, а не в комменты. Приложение x64 собрано или Any CPU?

Comment: @aepot, Any CPU

Comment: @АндрейПавлов а я вам говорил, что надо x64 собирать, либо явно указывать Registry Hive, но  вы ни того не сделали, не другого. И пришли с вопросом как раз про то, о чем я вас уже предупреждал.

Comment: Ну дурак я, что тут сказать...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136861/discussion-between---and-aepot).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все, проблема решена!
Надо было одну строчку поменять чуть-чуть...

Было:

```
using (var section = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(regWhiteList))
```

Стало:

```
using (var section = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(regWhiteList, true))
```

Будьте внимательны, друзья!)

Answer (score 0):

Есть подозрение, что у Вас просто прав не хватает.

Дело в том, что на накоторые части registry тоже есть права, так же, как и на файловую систему.

Проверить, так это или не так, можно либо посмотрев подробнее exception, либо попробовав запустить программу от имени более "могучего" (в смысле прав) пользователя.

Также, имейте в виду, что в компьютерах в составе домена эта схема еще усложняется: появляются группоаве политики, которые "перекрывают" настройки, внесенные в реестр локального компьютера.

Также, можете уточнить точное название ключа, в котром вы пытаетесь работать - может быть, все станет сразу понятно.

Comment: ключ реестра - registry.currentuser.software.whitelistmanager.whitelist (whitelistmanager.whitelist - эта ветка создается при загрузке программы)

Comment: А как права можно задать, запустить от имени администратора я попробовал - не вышло, думаю права должны помочь, только как их задавать?

Comment: А кто создаёт эту ветку? Есть подозрение, что у Вас на компе стоит ограничение на запуск программ, а Вы пытаетесь это ограничение обойти. Ну, судя по названию ветки реестра.

Comment: Ветку создает сама программа, из которой был представлен код

Comment: А какие способы есть на снятие ограничения, о котором вы говорите?

Comment: Хм, если эта ветка реестра создается этой же программой - то это выглядит странно... Но там Frehzy в комментариях привел оченьполезную ссылку, он аможет решить Вашу проблему

Comment: Я попробовал переделать код, вышло вот так : 'Applications.Remove(info);
            WhiteList.Add(info);
            using (var section = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(regWhiteList))
            {
                RegistryKey key = section.CreateSubKey(
                    info.RegistryKeyName, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
            }'